# Exception Thrown when attempting to compare using pointers

Tags: c, loops, pointers, exception

I am trying to make a loop that makes a pointer point to different elements in an array (Sorting in descending order) and I can't seem to get the comparing correctly since I always get an exception thrown. I also have a loop to print all the pointer's elements to test if the loop worked correctly. Never really used pointers before, but I tried to format them the same way I've seen on other websites when studying pointers. This is the part of code I am talking about:

```
//What I have included
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define MAX 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//Variables related to the loops
int nums[MAX], *ptrd[MAX];

//Loops in question (Assume nums[MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        if (*ptrd[i] < nums[j] && nums[j] <= *ptrd[i - 1])
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                if (ptrd[i] == ptrd[i - 1])
                    continue;
            }
            ptrd[i] = &nums[i];
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    printf("\n%d", *ptrd[i]);
}
```

Current full code so far (note the code in question here is different):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define MAX 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Variables
char input[20];
int nums[MAX], *ptrd[MAX], *ptra[MAX];
bool isValid;

//Methods
bool checkValidity();
void convertChars();
void resetInput();

int main()
{
    printf("Please enter 5 numbers (Separate each by spaces): ");
input:
    resetInput();
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", &input);
    isValid = checkValidity();

    if (isValid == false)
    {
        printf("Invalid input. Retry: ");
        goto input;
    }
    convertChars();

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            if (*ptrd[i] < nums[j])
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    if (ptrd[i] == ptrd[i - 1])
                        continue;
                    if (nums[j] <= *ptrd[i - 1])
                        ptrd[i] = &nums[i];
                }
                else
                    ptrd[i] = &nums[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", (*ptrd)[i]);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

bool checkValidity()
{
    bool multNum = false;
    int chars = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            if (input[i] == ' ' && multNum == true || input[i] == NULL && multNum == true)
                chars += 1;

            if (input[i] != ' ' && input[i] != NULL)
            {
                printf("\nIncorrect characters\n");
                return false;
            }
            if (input[i] == ' ' && multNum == false)
            {
                printf("\nToo many spaces at at once\n");
                return false;
            }
            if (input[i] == ' ' && multNum == true || input[i] == NULL && multNum == true)
                multNum = false;
        }
        else if (isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            multNum = true;
        }
    }
    if (chars != 5)
    {
        printf("\nIncorrect amount of nums (%d)\n", chars);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

void convertChars()
{
    int placeHolder, nums_ = 0, done = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 && done < 5; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            placeHolder = input[i] - '0';
            nums_ = (nums_ * 10) + placeHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            nums[done] = nums_;
            nums_ = 0;
            done += 1;
        }
    }
}

void resetInput()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        input[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: IS it a segmentation fault?

Comment: In that part, yes.

Comment: Maybe it could be, but it's why I put the (if i > 0) part so it would not try to look for a ptrd[-1]

Comment: This is the exception thrown: (Exception thrown at 0x00391B5C in PointerSortingBB.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.) found at (if (*ptrd[i] < nums[j] && nums[j] <= *ptrd[i - 1]))

Comment: where `ptrd` points, you didn't initialize anywhere. so when you do `*ptrd[i]`  obviously  gives seg. fault.

Comment: So I just add (ptrd = &nums) before the loop starts?

Comment: You have `for (int i = 0;`, so i starts off as 0. Then there is `ptrd[i - 1]`. Where do you expect that to read from? It accesses one below the array. Now assuming that does not yet cause a segfault you then do `*` on what you read from there. It is dereferencing a pointer. That pointer however is read from a place where you never write anything useful, especially not before... If you cannot decide on which part to debug more closely, start there.

Comment: Ah ok I'll fix it and see what I get

Comment: Exception is still thrown even if I move the part you specified into the if (i > 0) part of the loop

Comment: If you're still getting an exception after fixing the `*ptrd[i - 1]` problem, I'm guessing the bug must be coming from how the `ptrd` array is set up. Do you mind posting more of your code so we can see how the values of `ptrd` are set?

Comment: I edited the question to have all the code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `*ptrd[MAX]`, which results in an undefined behavior. Run your code with gdb, and it crashes with following output:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pringles/Desktop/a.out 
Please enter 5 numbers (Separate each by spaces): 3 2 1 5 6

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400719 in main () at test.c:37
37              if (*ptrd[i] < nums[j])
```

By printing the elements in ptrd, you can see all the elements point to 0x0:

```
(gdb) print ptrd
$1 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me get back on track on finishing my code and figure out what I had to do! Now I can finally progress.